# interface conversion panic when method is not actually missing

Tags: go

Somehow, at runtime, I am getting  the following **panic** message, even if it appears to me the method is properly defined to the struct that implements that interface.

```
panic: interface conversion: schema.MerchantResultset 
is not search.ResultsetInterface: missing method Add
```

This is the **interface** blueprint

```
type ResultsetInterface interface {
    Init(string)
    CacheSet(context.Context) error
    CacheSetPart(context.Context, int) error
    CacheGet(context.Context, string) error
    Add(interface{})
    AddResultset(interface{})
}
```

The following is the method that is reported **missing** during runtime, which is assigned to my struct MerchantResultset.

```
func (mr *MerchantResultset) Add(item interface{}) {
    mr.Data = append(mr.Data, item.(Merchant))
}
```

I am somehow very puzzled trying to understand what is actually being needed here

Comment: agree with Roland lllig's answer. Your panic is reporting `schema.MerchantResultset` is not implementing the method, this is true since Add method has pointer receiver. You need to pass `&MerchantResultset{}` around, not `MerchantResultset{}`.

Comment: Somehow both options still gives the same panic: 
1) item := schema.Merchant{}; resultSet.Add(item)
2) item := schema.Merchant{}; resultSet.Add(&item)

Comment: so basically it means that the only implementer would be func (mr MerchantResultset) Add(item interface{}) ?

Comment: you misunderstood, please have a look at the difference between [pointer receiver and non-pointer receiver](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/08/09/dont-get-bitten-by-pointer-vs-non-pointer-method-receivers-in-golang/) and how you could initialize them. Basically you need to do `item := &schema.Merchant{}` to get it implemented the interface.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Probably it’s because you are passing around a `MerchantResultset`, but the `Add` method is only defined for a *pointer to* that type.